# Trigger jenkins job with parameters from shell

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to trigger a trigger jenkins job from shell but as of now  no sucess.I tried both these methods

```
curl -u ceadmin:ceadmin -X POST http://abc-lnx:8080/job/ci_demo/build --data token=ci_build -data-urlencode json='{"parameter": [{"name":"Branch", "value":"master"}, {"name":"verbosity", "value":"high"}]}'
curl -X POST  http://abc-lnx:8080/job/ci_demo/buildWithParameters?token=ci_build&Branch=master
```

I have defined ce_admin as token in my job. also ce_admin is a admin user in Jenkins.Anonymous user  do not have  any permission other then read on jobs and views.

What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
#parameters:
username=user
password=password
jenkins_url=example.com/build
some_token=hi
job_name=dostuff

curl -u $username:$password -X POST https://$jenkins_url/job/$job_name/build\?token\=$some_token
```

So this should work for your example (I escaped "?", and "&"):

```
curl -u ceadmin:ceadmin -X POST  http://abc-lnx:8080/job/ci_demo/buildWithParameters\?token=ci_build\&Branch=master
```